# Combining multiple message fields using multiline codec in logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am using logstash 2.4.0

```
My output is like this:

{
      "@timestamp" => "2017-05-10T18:14:47.269Z",
         "message" => "[2017-01-14 10:59:58,591][WARN ][index.search.slowlog.query] [yaswanth] [bank][3] took[50ms], took_millis[50], types[details], stats[], search_type[QUERY_THEN_FETCH], total_shards[5], source[{\"sort\":[{\"balance\":{\"order\":\"asc\"}}]}], extra_source[], \r",
        "@version" => "1",
            "path" => "F:\\logstash-2.4.0\\logstash-2.4.0\\bin\\picaso.txt",
            "host" => "yaswanth",
       "TIMESTAMP" => "2017-01-14 10:59:58,591",
           "LEVEL" => "WARN",
           "QUERY" => "index.search.slowlog.query",
          "QUERY1" => "yaswanth",
      "INDEX-NAME" => "bank",
           "SHARD" => "3",
            "TOOK" => "50ms",
           "TOOKM" => 50,
           "types" => "details",
     "search_type" => "QUERY_THEN_FETCH",
    "total_shards" => "5",
    "source_query" => "{\"sort\":[{\"balance\":{\"order\":\"asc\"}}]}"
}
{
      "@timestamp" => "2017-05-10T18:14:47.270Z",
         "message" => "[2017-01-14 10:59:58,591][WARN ][index.search.slowlog.query] [yaswanth] [bank][2] took[50.2ms], took_millis[50], types[details], stats[], search_type[QUERY_THEN_FETCH], total_shards[5], source[{\"sort\":[{\"balance\":{\"order\":\"asc\"}}]}], extra_source[], \r",
        "@version" => "1",
            "path" => "F:\\logstash-2.4.0\\logstash-2.4.0\\bin\\picaso.txt",
            "host" => "yaswanth",
       "TIMESTAMP" => "2017-01-14 10:59:58,591",
           "LEVEL" => "WARN",
           "QUERY" => "index.search.slowlog.query",
          "QUERY1" => "yaswanth",
      "INDEX-NAME" => "bank",
           "SHARD" => "2",
            "TOOK" => "50.2ms",
           "TOOKM" => 50,
           "types" => "details",
     "search_type" => "QUERY_THEN_FETCH",
    "total_shards" => "5",
    "source_query" => "{\"sort\":[{\"balance\":{\"order\":\"asc\"}}]}"
}
```

But what i want is like this

```
{
          "@timestamp" => "2017-05-10T18:14:47.269Z",
             "message" => "[2017-01-14 10:59:58,591][WARN ][index.search.slowlog.query] [yaswanth] [bank][3] took[50ms], took_millis[50], types[details], stats[], search_type[QUERY_THEN_FETCH], total_shards[5], source[{\"sort\":[{\"balance\":{\"order\":\"asc\"}}]}], extra_source[], \r",[2017-01-14 10:59:58,591][WARN ][index.search.slowlog.query] [yaswanth] [bank][2] took[50.2ms], took_millis[50], types[details], stats[], search_type[QUERY_THEN_FETCH], total_shards[5], source[{\"sort\":[{\"balance\":{\"order\":\"asc\"}}]}], extra_source[], \r"
            "@version" => "1",
                "path" => "F:\\logstash-2.4.0\\logstash-2.4.0\\bin\\picaso.txt",
                "host" => "yaswanth",
           "TIMESTAMP" => "2017-01-14 10:59:58,591",
               "LEVEL" => "WARN",
               "QUERY" => "index.search.slowlog.query",
              "QUERY1" => "yaswanth",
          "INDEX-NAME" => "bank",
               "SHARD" => "3",
                "TOOK" => "50ms",
               "TOOKM" => 50,
               "types" => "details",
         "search_type" => "QUERY_THEN_FETCH",
        "total_shards" => "5",
        "source_query" => "{\"sort\":[{\"balance\":{\"order\":\"asc\"}}]}"
    }
```

I want to send all the message fields from multiple events to a single event for sending email .

Is there anything wrong in the above config ? Do i have to use aggregate filter for this type of requirement?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share your logstash configuration?

Comment: I Edited my question

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to aggregate a number of events of at the level of the [file input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html) before sending them to the output plugin. A good example is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33377193/combining-multiple-events-in-logstash).

You might have to modify your grok filter a little bite.

Comment: Means you are saying to sum all the logs at once in the input and send them as a one event right?

Comment: Yes. that is what I'm talking about.

Comment: Whether i have to change both input and grok ?

Comment: Well, I guess so. I might be of addition help if you provide some lines of your input file.

Comment: Thanks, but multiline codec will add all the messages but i want to apply if condition so i had used aggregate filter for that.